# Where should the code to be executed be in a try statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
mp.events.addCommand('admin', (player, _, targetPlayer, targetAdminLevel) => {
    const targetSocialID = targetPlayer.rgscId;
    try {
        if (player.adminLevel < 8)  throw "Este comando só está disponível para administradores de nível superior a 8.";
        if (!targetPlayer) throw "Uso: /admin <ID/NOME> <NÍVEL DE ADMINISTRADOR>.";
        if (player.adminLevel <= targetAdminLevel) throw "Não podes promover alguém a um nível superior ao teu.";
        if (!global.findPlayer(targetPlayer)) throw "Esse jogador não existe ou não está online.";
        if (!targetAdminLevel) throw `Não definiste para que nível pretendes promover ${targetPlayer}.`;
        if (isNaN(targetAdminLevel)) throw "O nível de administrador deve ser um número."
    }
    catch(err) {
        player.outputChatBox(`!{${corErro}}${err}`)
    }
    finally {
        console.log("Finally")
    }
});
```

I have written the code above. It checks for a multitude of errors. My question is: where should I put the code to be executed when none of those errors happen?

If no errors, then this.

Comment: Outside the `try-catch` block can be accepted.

Comment: Just inside the `try` block, after the last `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a flag for that purpose:

```
mp.events.addCommand('admin', (player, _, targetPlayer, targetAdminLevel) => {
    const targetSocialID = targetPlayer.rgscId;
    var isSuccess = true;
    try {
        if (player.adminLevel < 8)  throw "Este comando só está disponível para administradores de nível superior a 8.";
        if (!targetPlayer) throw "Uso: /admin <ID/NOME> <NÍVEL DE ADMINISTRADOR>.";
        if (player.adminLevel <= targetAdminLevel) throw "Não podes promover alguém a um nível superior ao teu.";
        if (!global.findPlayer(targetPlayer)) throw "Esse jogador não existe ou não está online.";
        if (!targetAdminLevel) throw `Não definiste para que nível pretendes promover ${targetPlayer}.`;
        if (isNaN(targetAdminLevel)) throw "O nível de administrador deve ser um número."
    }
    catch(err) {
        isSuccess = false;
        player.outputChatBox(`!{${corErro}}${err}`)
    }
    finally {
        console.log("Finally")
    }
    if (isSuccess) /*Do something here*/;
});
```

You can make it more general:

```
function catcher(tryHandler, catchHandler, finallyHandler) {
    var isSuccess = true;
    try {
        tryHandler();
    } 
    catch (err) {
        isSuccess = false;
        catchHandler();
    }
    finally {
        finallyHandler();
    }
}
```

And you can use it like

```
if (catcher(tryHandler, catchHandler, finallyHandler)) {
    //All was successful
} else {
    //There was some error
}
```

You can use the [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as well, fulfilling the promise in the `if` and rejecting it in the `else`.

Comment: Hi. I did as you said in the first example, however the code is still executing even tho I receive the error message. What's wrong?
```
mp.events.addCommand('admin', (player, _, targetPlayer, targetAdminLevel) => {
    const targetSocialID = targetPlayer.rgscId;
    var isSuccess = true;
    try {
    }
    catch(err) {
        player.outputChatBox(`!{${corErro}}${err}`)
    }
    finally {
        console.log("Finally")
    }
    if (isSuccess) {
        player.outputChatBox("Sucesso")
    }
});

```

Comment: @HugoAlmeida you did not set isSuccess to false in the catch. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`throw` will terminate the current execution context and pass control flow to the nearest `try` stack ancestor's associated `catch`. So, when there are no errors, put statements right above the `try`'s `}`:

```
mp.events.addCommand('admin', (player, _, targetPlayer, targetAdminLevel) => {
    const targetSocialID = targetPlayer.rgscId;
    try {
        if (player.adminLevel < 8)  throw "Este comando só está disponível para administradores de nível superior a 8.";
        if (!targetPlayer) throw "Uso: /admin <ID/NOME> <NÍVEL DE ADMINISTRADOR>.";
        if (player.adminLevel <= targetAdminLevel) throw "Não podes promover alguém a um nível superior ao teu.";
        if (!global.findPlayer(targetPlayer)) throw "Esse jogador não existe ou não está online.";
        if (!targetAdminLevel) throw `Não definiste para que nível pretendes promover ${targetPlayer}.`;
        if (isNaN(targetAdminLevel)) throw "O nível de administrador deve ser um número."

        console.log('No errors were found!'); // <---------------------
    }
    catch(err) {
        player.outputChatBox(`!{${corErro}}${err}`)
    }
    finally {
        console.log("Finally")
    }
});
```

Comment: One subtle point is that the user might want the success handler to be outside the try-catch-finally, because 1. He/she might want errors after that chunk of code not to be handled like in the catch block, 2. He/she might want to do some operations in the finally before the success handler.